# How to set initial custom variable date upon datepicker opening in Materialize

Tags: javascript, materialize

I use two Materialize datepickers. Upon opening the date picker I want the date that in already in html input field to be displayed / used by the date picker. I was thinkig of `onOpen` callback and there use native `.setDate()` function. But I got two date pickers and did not find if onOpen accepts any arguments.

```
var datepickerOptions ={
        
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  autoClose : "true",
  firstDay : 1,
  onOpen : function(arg) {
   console.log(arg)
  }
}  
  
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
    var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, datepickerOptions);
  });
```

I am using Materialize v1.0. and working [jsFiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/x7qa1w90/5/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is sufficient to add `setDefaultDate: true` option to your original example:

```js
var datepickerOptions = {
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  autoClose : "true",
  firstDay : 1,
  setDefaultDate: true
}
```

This will automatically pick up the value you've added to your `input` fields in HTML markup. **No need** to set the date **explicitly** in the JavaScript code.

This is minimal working Fiddle based on your example:
https://jsfiddle.net/3j6cezfy/

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```js
var date_picker_1;
var date_picker_2;
var datepickerOptions = {
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  autoClose: "true",
  firstDay: 1,
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
  var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, datepickerOptions);
  date_picker_1 =  M.Datepicker.getInstance(document.getElementById("date_picker_1"));
  date_picker_2 =  M.Datepicker.getInstance(document.getElementById("date_picker_2"));
  date_picker_1.setDate(new Date("2021-05-12"));
  date_picker_2.setDate(new Date("2021-05-25"));
});
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/doz2htv6/34/

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to do it with `onOpen` and `setDate` methods (maybe to have more fine-grained control on how the date is set, or handle formatting of the `value` attribute), you could use the `this.el.value` property to retrieve a pre-configured date. Here's a working example based on your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2rLg0c1z/.

```
var datepickerOptions = {
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  autoClose: "true",
  firstDay: 1,
  onOpen: function() {
    this.setDate(new Date(this.el.value));
  }
}
```

Otherwise more simple way to automatically parse and set the date from `value` attribute would be to use `setDefaultDate` property, which would basically do the same on the initialization of the widget:

```
var datepickerOptions = {
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  autoClose: "true",
  firstDay: 1,
  setDefaultDate: true
}
```

Comment: yes, you are right. I thought I had to use arguments of the callback but I can "just" use `this`. Thank you

Comment: would you know if the `arg` does anything?

Comment: `el` stands for element? How did you know how to use it? Why not just this.value?

Comment: I've checked the doc for the pickers, here it is: https://materializecss.com/pickers.html. And according to doc the `onOpen` event doesn't take any arguments, so the `arg` would be `undefined` in this case.

Comment: yes, but how about `this`. Can I use this every time I use call back?

Comment: Yes, `this` points to the date picker itself when events functions are fired. I didn't know if from start, but I knew that it can be the case from my experience, so I did `console.lof(this)` in the `onOpen` to verify my assumption first.

Comment: You are welcome, I'm glad that I was able to help!

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use the `defaultDate` and `setDefaultDate` options from the [documentation](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html), and use them to initialize each date picker.

You set the `defaultDate` field to a date object created from the input value, and you set the `setDefaultDate` field to true to use the default date in the input when you open it.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const pickers = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
    pickers.forEach((picker) => {
        const options = {
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            autoClose : true,
            firstDay : 1,
            defaultDate: new Date(picker.value),
            setDefaultDate: true
        };
        M.Datepicker.init(picker, options);
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    padding: 3em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<input class="datepicker" type=text value="2021-05-12" />
<input class="datepicker" type=text value="2021-05-25" />
```